# Authenticate users on account through API

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-api

I wanted to implement something that looks like an embedded login, basically what Salesforce has, but with HubSpot. From what I've been searching, I can't find anything like embedded login for HubSpot, and trying to search through the API, I still haven't found anything that helps me implement an authentication on my website with HubSpot, is there a way to implement this feature with HubSpot?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a app on Hubspot and in similar fashion like Salesforce authenticate users and redirect them on your endpoint and use that code to get an access token!

https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token

Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).